# How to retrieve multiple images from Firebase Firestorage and maintaining their order in Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve multiple images from Firestorage, each image is associated with a document in Firebase Firestore database (the document ID is equivalent to the image name).

After retrieving all the documents IDs I inserted it into `ArrayList<String> POSTS_IDs` and I want to fill the `ArrayList<File> IMAGE_FILE` with the images but the problem is that the images always take a random order and do not maintain the order of the POSTS_IDs.

I mean if the index 3 of POSTS_IDs is equal to "image3", the index 3 of IMAGE_FILE will be image 5 or 6 (it is random some times it comes with the right order).

I want to know if my way is wrong or what is the problem.
Thank you

```
try {

                for (int i = 0; i < POSTS_IDs.size(); i++) {
                    final File file = File.createTempFile(POSTS_IDs.get(i), ".jpg");


                    StorageReference reference1 = storageReference.child("images/posts/" + POSTS_IDs.get(i) + ".jpg");
                    reference1.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+taskSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            IMAGE_FILE.add(file); // adding the images to the IMAGE_FILE ArrayList<File>

                        }
                    });

                }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

Comment: The problem was solved after I removed the onSuccessListener.
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove the onSuccessListener. here you have IMAGE_FILE.add(file); for the array list so no need of onSuccessListener